# session parameters

Tags: php, session, redirect, session-variables

i did this code :

file index.php:

```
  <?php
        if (isset($_POST['valider']))
            { if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
                   require("function.php");
                        $email                   = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
                        $password                    = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
                        if(!VerifierAdresseMail($email)){?>
                        <script>alert('invalid mail');</script>
    <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        if(!authentification($email,$password))
                        {?>
                        <script>alert('logging failed');</script>
                        <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        header('Location: choice.php'); 
                        }}
                        }
        ?>
```

In function.php:

```
<?php
function VerifierAdresseMail($adresse)  
{  
   $Syntaxe='#^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$#';  
   if(preg_match($Syntaxe,$adresse))  
      return true;  
   else  
     return false;  
}
function statistics($id){
$HOST_DB ="localhost";
                $NAME_DB="makempf3_captcha";
                $USER_DB ="root";
                $PWD_DB="";

                $connect = mysql_connect($HOST_DB,$USER_DB,$PWD_DB);
                $db=mysql_select_db($NAME_DB);
?><script>alert(<?php echo $cle ?>);</script><?php              
                $Log_query=mysql_query(
                    "   
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM  tbl_captcha
                        WHERE user_id ='$id'


                        ") or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION['success'] =0;
$_SESSION['fail'] =0;
                      if ($Log_query == true && mysql_num_rows($Log_query) >0) {
?><script>alert('heni');</script><?php
                               while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query) ) {
                                $_SESSION['success'] += $Res_user['success'];
                                $_SESSION['fail'] += $Res_user['fail'];


                            }
}





}
function authentification($mail,$pwd_U){

                 $HOST_DB ="localhost";
                $NAME_DB="makempf3_captcha";
                $USER_DB ="root";
                $PWD_DB="";

                $connect = mysql_connect($HOST_DB,$USER_DB,$PWD_DB);
                $db=mysql_select_db($NAME_DB);          

                $Log_query=mysql_query(
                    "   
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM  tbl_user
                        WHERE email ='$mail'
                        AND   user_pass   ='$pwd_U'

                        ") or die(mysql_error());

                        if ($Log_query == true && mysql_num_rows($Log_query) >0) {
                            $Res = array();
                            while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query) ) {
                               $_SESSION['mail'] = $mail;
                                $_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd_U;
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $Res_user['id'];


                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        else return false;

}




?>
```

when i verify $_SESSION['id'] in choice.php, it is null, but in index.php (before redirection) it has a value. i don't understand why i lost this session variable

Comment: the file that i redirect to it (header('Location: choice.php');) in index.php

Comment: For the love of god, man, *formatting!*  Please don't copy and paste directly from other web pages without going through and formatting the code per Stack Overflow's markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isset()` check isn't sufficient, because it would only be executed if `$_SESSION` is NULL, and it will never be - it's an empty array instead and it always exists, even before you call `session_start()`.

Comment: i replaced if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); } by session_start(); but the same problem

Comment: This is a fantastic answer to help people understand why isset() doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always run `session_start();` to be able to use sessions, even if you're only reading them. Also, `$_SESSION` is a superglobal, so it is never empty : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php.

Comment: it is not empty look at the file function.php

Comment: I mean that your condition to run `session_start` will never be true. You have to run this function into every page where you use sessions.

Comment: i replaced if `(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` by `session_start(); but the same problem`

Comment: Are you running `session_start` in choice.php ?

Comment: no a simple html page with  an alert `<script>alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>);</script>`

Comment: There is your problem then. Read the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can run session_start without your isset() check. From the manual:

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Don't forget to run session_start in choice.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Index.php should probably be like this. You should never tell the user which part of the login they got wrong..... only that it failed.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("function.php");

if (isset($_POST['valider']))
    { 
        $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
        $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
        if(VerifierAdresseMail($email) && authentification($email,$password))
            {
                header('Location: choice.php');
            }
            else
               {
                   echo "Invalid Login";
               }
?>
```